# Filling/replacing an empty cell in a column with the first character in a string from a previous column

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, replace, strsplit

I have a column of data labeled in the following string format: "1.2.a.2021"; I want to replace the corresponding row in a "wk#" column currently filled with NA to the first number in the string (in this case it would be "1"). I am using strsplit() to split up the string into various characters/or made them numeric, but I want to create a for loop that will then take that first character from each row/first column and put it into the new column respective cell. There are 13 weeks in the but hundreds of data points so a loop would work best to find and match the number.
See example below.

| sample | ng | wk# |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.2.a.2021 | 0.4 | NA |

Comment: Perhaps you want `substr` `df1[["wk#"]] <- substr(df1$sample, 1, 1)`

Answer (score 3):

We may use `sub` to match the `.` followed by other characters and replace with blank

```
df1[["wk#"]] <- sub("\\..*", "", df1$sample)
```

---

Or may use `substr` as well if the intention is to get the first character

```
df1[["wk#"]] <- substr(df1$sample, 1, 1)
```

---

When we use `strsplit` to split at the `.`, it needs a loop to extract the first element from the `list`.

```
df1[["wk#"]] <- sapply(strsplit(df1$sample, ".", fixed = TRUE), `[`, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun! That worked well. Next question is, how can I then search for the second number in the string (example 1. 2.a.2021 , "2" as the number) and then fill a new column (already made with NA) with "a"? I have begun trying here: 
 if (substr(dm_2021$sample, 3, 3) == "1"){
 ###want to use a function to fill/enter the respective cell with "a"###
}

Comment: @LexiHeger  You could either do `sub("^\\d+\\.\\s*(\\d+).*", "\\1", df1$sample)` i.e. `sub("^\\d+\\.\\s*(\\d+).*", "\\1", "1. 2.a.2021")#
[1] "2"`

Comment: I think I am confused; does that pull the second number exclusively? If so, I understand that , but how can I use that to then insert "a" into a new, currently empty column when "2" is seen as the second character? I intend on using an If statement but I am unsure how. Thank you.

Comment: @LexiHeger you need `a` sorry, i was thinking that you need the number.  `sub("^\\d+\\.\\s*\\d+\\.([a-z])+\\..*", "\\1", "1. 2.a.2021")#[1] "a"`

Comment: When I used that regex, that produces a list of the various sample names in column "sample," and does not place anything in the new column. Why do we use sub() and not substr()?

Comment: @LexiHeger not clear.  I get `df1$new <- sub("^\\d+\\.\\s*\\d+\\.([a-z])+\\..*", "\\1", df1$sample); df1$new#
[1] "a"`.  The data used is `df1 <- structure(list(sample = "1.2.a.2021", ng = 0.4, wk = NA), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))`

Answer (score 2):

@akrun already provides nearly all possible solution. Here is one more making use of `sub` and a different regular expression:

```
df$wk <- sub('(^.).*', '\\1', df$sample)

      sample  ng wk
1 1.2.a.2021 0.4  1
```